# Flutter : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences) only on ios

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, plugins, cocoapods

So, I've been researching for this error for a week now and there are a lot of solution I found. One of the solution is changing some of android file such as `MainActivity.kt` and so on. So since the error only occur on iOS, I can't use every solution for Android.

The other solution was to use `SharedPreferences.SetMockInitialValues({})`. This solution solves the exception, however when I run the code on my iOS phone,The data was not persisted.

I also did all the restart uninstall app with flutter clean and so on. Also removed the pods,Podfile.lock, derived data and pod install. I also put `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized()` and it still the same.

I also found out that this exception mostly occur to people who use background services such as [Workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager). I dont use that package, however, I do use a somewhat similar package which is [flutter foreground task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task). Is it because of that?

I used mac mini M1 chip and debug on my iPhone XR. I don't get the exception from when running the code from Xcode, however the app still stuck. And when i run the code on vs code, it give the said exception.

I hope I can get a new answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I just need to upgrade the flutter_foreground_task to the latest version since the problem happens because of the plugin itself.